# This function keeps causing my program to stop working c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Whenever I call this function my program stops working, I cannot seem to figure out why though. Here's my code snippet :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void FindReplace(char Memory[], string FindWord, string  ReplaceWord, const int  MAXNUMCHARS)
   {
        int i = 0;
        int SizeWord = FindWord.length();
        int SizeReplace = ReplaceWord.length();

 for(i = 0; i <= MAXNUMCHARS; i++)
   {

       if(Memory[i] == FindWord[i] && Memory[i+1] == FindWord[i+1] && Memory[i+2] ==        FindWord[i+2])
       {
             Memory[i] = ReplaceWord[i];
             Memory[i+1] = ReplaceWord[i+1];
             Memory[i+2] = ReplaceWord[i+2];
       }

 }
}
```

and heres the code that calls it

```
if(option == 'F')
{
     FindReplace(Memory, FindWord, ReplaceWord, MAXNUMCHARS);
     OutputMemoryToFile(Memory , Out);//copies array to output file
     cout << "String 'the' has been found and replaced with 'can'";
     cout << endl;
}
```

any ideas please? :/

Comment: Can you show the code which calls this please?  I presume the problem involves reading beyond the end of `FindWord` and/or `ReplaceWord` but we'd need to see the calling code to be sure.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this `i <= MAXNUMCHARS`, shouldn't it be only `<` instead of `<=`. Just a guess?

Comment: What is the value of `MAXNUMCHARS` ? How much memory is allocated for `Memory` and for `ReplaceWord` ?

Comment: What does `program stops working` mean ?

Comment: nope even when I make it < MAXNUMCHARS it still stops working

Comment: It might be because of running out of bounds `Memory[i+1]`,`Memory[i+2]`. You should ensure that `i+2` is less than 1000. You might have to make it `i < (MAXNUMCHARS - 2)`

Comment: how is `Memory` declared ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your calling code doesn't ensure that `Memory`, `FindWord` and `ReplaceWord` are at least `MAXNUMCHARS+3` characters long (it's a guess though, since you do not post the calling code).

Comment: I saw it :). Are `Memory`, `FindWord` and `ReplaceWord` filled to `MAXNUMCHARS+3`? Otherwise, your code will allways fail.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a `break;` in your finding `if` statement;

Comment: will it really make a difference?

Comment: if you want  to `return` as soon as you've made the replacement it does.

Answer (score 0):

also you can go out of bounds
you check i <= MAXNUMCHARS, but use i+2